# ListView inside / with spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, android-spinner

Experts,I been struggling to solve the below issue. Have got code which basically searching the data using edittext to spinner which is working fine. But issue is i am unable to open the spinner to see the inside contents.Used AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener but no use.

Your most welcome to modify the code as per your input to solve the same.

CourseSearchActivity.java

```js
package edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private DBHelper db;
  private List < Course > allCoursesList;
  private List < Offering > allOfferingsList;
  private List < Offering > filteredOfferingsList;

  private EditText courseTitleEditText;
  private Spinner ok;
  private ListView offeringsListView;

  private OfferingListAdapter offeringListAdapter;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_search);

    deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.importCoursesFromCSV("courses.csv");

    db.importOfferingsFromCSV("offerings.csv");

    allOfferingsList = db.getAllOfferings();
    filteredOfferingsList = new ArrayList < > (allOfferingsList);

    allCoursesList = db.getAllCourses();

    courseTitleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseTitleEditText);
    courseTitleEditText.addTextChangedListener(courseTitleTextWatcher);

    ok = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ok);


    offeringListAdapter = new OfferingListAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);
    ok.setAdapter(offeringListAdapter);
    ArrayAdapter < String > instructorSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
      (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllInstructorNames());
    //ok.setAdapter(instructorSpinnerAdapter);
    // ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);


  }
  private String[] getAllInstructorNames() {
    String[] instructorNames = new String[allCoursesList.size() + 1];
    instructorNames[0] = "[Select Course]";
    for (int i = 1; i < instructorNames.length; i++) {
      instructorNames[i] = allCoursesList.get(i - 1).getTitle();
    }
    return instructorNames;
  }

  public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
      if (input.equals("")) {

      } else {
        String name = ok.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(CourseSearchActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        offeringListAdapter.clear();
        for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList) {
          // If the course title starts with the user input,
          // add it to the listAdapter
          Course course = offering.getCourse();
          if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(input))
            offeringListAdapter.add(offering);
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


    }
  };
  public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      String selectedInstructorName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
      if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
        offeringListAdapter.clear();
        for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
          offeringListAdapter.add(offering);
      } else {
        offeringListAdapter.clear();

      }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {
      adapterView.setSelection(0);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  };

  public void reset(View view) {
    courseTitleEditText.setText("");
    ok.setSelection(0);
  }

}
```

```js
package edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder;

el Paulding
  *
  /
public class Offering {
  private int mCRN;
  private int mSemesterCode;
  private Course mCourse;


  public Offering(int CRN, int semesterCode, Course course) {
    mCRN = CRN;
    mSemesterCode = semesterCode;
    mCourse = course;

  }

  public Offering(int semesterCode, Course course) {
    mSemesterCode = semesterCode;
    mCourse = course;
  }

  public int getCRN() {
    return mCRN;
  }

  public int getSemesterCode() {
    return mSemesterCode;
  }

  public String getSemesterName() {
    switch (mSemesterCode) {
      case 201731:
        return "Fall 2017";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }
  public void setSemesterCode(int semesterCode) {
    mSemesterCode = semesterCode;
  }

  public Course getCourse() {
    return mCourse;
  }

  public void setCourse(Course course) {
    mCourse = course;
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Offering{" +
      "CRN=" + mCRN +
      ", SemesterCode=" + mSemesterCode +
      ", Course=" + mCourse +

      '}';
  }
}
```

course

```js
package edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder;


public class Course {
  private int mId;
  private String mAlpha;
  private String mNumber;
  private String mTitle;

  public Course(int id, String alpha, String number, String title) {
    mId = id;
    mAlpha = alpha;
    mNumber = number;
    mTitle = title;
  }

  public Course(String alpha, String number, String title) {
    this(-1, alpha, number, title);
  }

  public int getId() {
    return mId;
  }

  public String getAlpha() {
    return mAlpha;
  }

  public void setAlpha(String alpha) {
    mAlpha = alpha;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return mNumber;
  }

  public String getFullName() {
    return mAlpha + " " + mNumber;
  }

  public void setNumber(String number) {
    mNumber = number;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Course{" +
      "Id=" + mId +
      ", Alpha='" + mAlpha + '\'' +
      ", Number='" + mNumber + '\'' +
      ", Title='" + mTitle + '\'' +
      '}';
  }
}
```

DBHELPER.java

```js
package edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private Context mContext;

  //TASK: DEFINE THE DATABASE VERSION AND NAME  (DATABASE CONTAINS MULTIPLE TABLES)
  static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OCC";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  //TASK: DEFINE THE FIELDS (COLUMN NAMES) FOR THE COURSES TABLE
  public static final String COURSES_TABLE = "Courses";
  public static final String COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID = "_id";
  public static final String FIELD_ALPHA = "alpha";
  public static final String FIELD_NUMBER = "number";
  public static final String FIELD_TITLE = "title";

  //TASK: DEFINE THE FIELDS (COLUMN NAMES) FOR THE INSTRUCTORS TABLE


  //TASK: DEFINE THE FIELDS (COLUMN NAMES) FOR THE OFFERINGS TABLE
  private static final String OFFERINGS_TABLE = "Offerings";
  private static final String OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID = "crn";
  private static final String FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE = "semester_code";
  public static final String FIELD_COURSE_ID = "course_id";

  public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + COURSES_TABLE + "(" +
      COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      FIELD_ALPHA + " TEXT, " +
      FIELD_NUMBER + " TEXT, " +
      FIELD_TITLE + " TEXT" + ")";
    database.execSQL(createQuery);



    createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + OFFERINGS_TABLE + "(" +
      OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE + " INTEGER, " +
      FIELD_COURSE_ID + " INTEGER, "

      +
      "FOREIGN KEY(" + FIELD_COURSE_ID + ") REFERENCES "

      +
      COURSES_TABLE + "(" + COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + ")" +
      ")";
    database.execSQL(createQuery);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,
    int oldVersion,
    int newVersion) {
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COURSES_TABLE);

    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + OFFERINGS_TABLE);
    onCreate(database);
  }

  //********** COURSE TABLE OPERATIONS:  ADD, GETALL, EDIT, DELETE

  public void addCourse(Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIELD_ALPHA, course.getAlpha());
    values.put(FIELD_NUMBER, course.getNumber());
    values.put(FIELD_TITLE, course.getTitle());

    db.insert(COURSES_TABLE, null, values);

    // CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION
    db.close();
  }

  public ArrayList < Course > getAllCourses() {
    ArrayList < Course > coursesList = new ArrayList < > ();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryList, null);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
      COURSES_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_ALPHA,
        FIELD_NUMBER,
        FIELD_TITLE
      },
      null,
      null,
      null, null, null, null);

    //COLLECT EACH ROW IN THE TABLE
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        Course course =
          new Course(cursor.getInt(0),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3));
        coursesList.add(course);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return coursesList;
  }

  public void deleteCourse(Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // DELETE THE TABLE ROW
    db.delete(COURSES_TABLE, COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(course.getId())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public void deleteAllCourses() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(COURSES_TABLE, null, null);
    db.close();
  }

  public void updateCourse(Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIELD_ALPHA, course.getAlpha());
    values.put(FIELD_NUMBER, course.getNumber());
    values.put(FIELD_TITLE, course.getTitle());

    db.update(COURSES_TABLE, values, COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(course.getId())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public Course getCourse(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
      COURSES_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_ALPHA,
        FIELD_NUMBER,
        FIELD_TITLE
      },
      COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + "=?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(id)
      },
      null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
      cursor.moveToFirst();

    Course course = new Course(
      cursor.getInt(0),
      cursor.getString(1),
      cursor.getString(2),
      cursor.getString(3));

    db.close();
    return course;
  }




  //********** OFFERING TABLE OPERATIONS:  ADD, GETALL, EDIT, DELETE

  public void addOffering(int crn, int semesterCode, int courseId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID, crn);
    values.put(FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE, semesterCode);
    values.put(FIELD_COURSE_ID, courseId);


    db.insert(OFFERINGS_TABLE, null, values);

    // CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION
    db.close();
  }

  public ArrayList < Offering > getAllOfferings() {
    ArrayList < Offering > offeringsList = new ArrayList < > ();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryList, null);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
      OFFERINGS_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE,
        FIELD_COURSE_ID
      },
      null,
      null,
      null, null, null, null);

    //COLLECT EACH ROW IN THE TABLE
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        Course course = getCourse(cursor.getInt(2));
        //Instructor instructor = getInstructor(cursor.getInt(3));
        Offering offering = new Offering(cursor.getInt(0),
          cursor.getInt(1), course);

        offeringsList.add(offering);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return offeringsList;
  }

  public void deleteOffering(Offering offering) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // DELETE THE TABLE ROW
    db.delete(OFFERINGS_TABLE, OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(offering.getCRN())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public void deleteAllOfferings() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(OFFERINGS_TABLE, null, null);
    db.close();
  }

  public void updateOffering(Offering offering) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE, offering.getSemesterCode());
    values.put(FIELD_COURSE_ID, offering.getCourse().getId());


    db.update(OFFERINGS_TABLE, values, OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(offering.getCRN())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public Offering getOffering(int crn) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
      OFFERINGS_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE,
        FIELD_COURSE_ID
      },
      OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + "=?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(crn)
      },
      null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
      cursor.moveToFirst();

    Course course = getCourse(cursor.getInt(2));
    //Instructor instructor = getInstructor(cursor.getInt(3));
    Offering offering = new Offering(cursor.getInt(0),
      cursor.getInt(1), course);


    db.close();
    return offering;
  }

  public Cursor getAllLabelsAsCursor() {
    String[] columns = new String[] {
      "rowid AS _id, *"
    }; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(COURSES_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
  }



  public boolean importCoursesFromCSV(String csvFileName) {
    AssetManager manager = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream inStream;
    try {
      inStream = manager.open(csvFileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    String line;
    try {
      while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        if (fields.length != 4) {
          Log.d("OCC Course Finder", "Skipping Bad CSV Row: " + Arrays.toString(fields));
          continue;
        }
        int id = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].trim());
        String alpha = fields[1].trim();
        String number = fields[2].trim();
        String title = fields[3].trim();
        addCourse(new Course(id, alpha, number, title));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }



  public boolean importOfferingsFromCSV(String csvFileName) {
    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
      inStream = am.open(csvFileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    String line;
    try {
      while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        if (fields.length != 4) {
          Log.d("OCC Course Finder", "Skipping Bad CSV Row: " + Arrays.toString(fields));
          continue;
        }
        int crn = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].trim());
        int semesterCode = Integer.parseInt(fields[1].trim());
        int courseId = Integer.parseInt(fields[2].trim());

        addOffering(crn, semesterCode, courseId);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

CourseSearchActivity.java

```js
package edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private DBHelper db;
  private List < Course > allCoursesList;
  private List < Offering > allOfferingsList;
  private List < Offering > filteredOfferingsList;

  private EditText courseTitleEditText;
  private Spinner ok;
  private ListView offeringsListView;

  private OfferingListAdapter offeringListAdapter;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_search);

    deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.importCoursesFromCSV("courses.csv");

    db.importOfferingsFromCSV("offerings.csv");

    allOfferingsList = db.getAllOfferings();
    filteredOfferingsList = new ArrayList < > (allOfferingsList);

    allCoursesList = db.getAllCourses();

    courseTitleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseTitleEditText);
    courseTitleEditText.addTextChangedListener(courseTitleTextWatcher);

    ok = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ok);


    offeringListAdapter = new OfferingListAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);
    ok.setAdapter(offeringListAdapter);
    ArrayAdapter < String > instructorSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
      (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllInstructorNames());
    //ok.setAdapter(instructorSpinnerAdapter);
    // ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);


  }
  private String[] getAllInstructorNames() {
    String[] instructorNames = new String[allCoursesList.size() + 1];
    instructorNames[0] = "[Select Course]";
    for (int i = 1; i < instructorNames.length; i++) {
      instructorNames[i] = allCoursesList.get(i - 1).getTitle();
    }
    return instructorNames;
  }

  public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
      if (input.equals("")) {

      } else {
        String name = ok.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(CourseSearchActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        offeringListAdapter.clear();
        for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList) {
          // If the course title starts with the user input,
          // add it to the listAdapter
          Course course = offering.getCourse();
          if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(input))
            offeringListAdapter.add(offering);
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


    }
  };
  public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      String selectedInstructorName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
      if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
        offeringListAdapter.clear();
        for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
          offeringListAdapter.add(offering);
      } else {
        offeringListAdapter.clear();

      }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {
      adapterView.setSelection(0);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  };

  public void reset(View view) {
    courseTitleEditText.setText("");
    ok.setSelection(0);
  }

}
```

Receiving following error. while clicking the spinner

```js
04 - 11 14: 52: 59.657 8011 - 8011 / edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.orangecoastcollege.cs273.occcoursefinder, PID: 8011
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method viewOfferingDetails(View) in a parent or ancestor Context
for android: onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.LinearLayout with id 'offeringListLinearLayout'
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java: 4757)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java: 4716)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java: 5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java: 22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 776)
```

Comment: Did you tried changing you spinner type to simple_spinner_dropdown_item  in your arrayadapter

Comment: @Uday Ramjiyani its not working.. can you help with my above codings

Comment: Hello admin need to know how to bring my question attention to experts;) Nice to have if @ option is all for instead of only commented people.Seems people are not interested in Android tweak:)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Auto Complete textView